# React Native 0.60.5 react-native-splash-screen configuration android

Tags: android, react-native, splash-screen

while I was doing the setup of the library, following what's said there: https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen
I found that in MainActivity.java there's no more the onCreate method.

MainActivity.java RN 0.60

```
package com.testApp;

import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

    /**
     * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript.
     * This is used to schedule rendering of the component.
     */
    @Override
    protected String getMainComponentName() {
        return "testApp";
    }
}
```

So I tried to do the setup in the getMainComponentName method:
MainActivity.java

```
package com.testApp;

import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import org.devio.rn.splashscreen.SplashScreen;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

    /**
     * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript.
     * This is used to schedule rendering of the component.
     */

    @Override
    protected String getMainComponentName() {
        SplashScreen.show(this);
        return "testApp";
    }
}
```

but when I try to compile it gives me this error: `error: cannot find symbol variable SplashScreen`

Anyone knows how to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Override the onCreate method inside the MainActivity, like this :

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        SplashScreen.show(this);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
```

don't forget to `import android.os.Bundle` and `import org.devio.rn.splashscreen.SplashScreen;`

Comment: Hi there, following your fix, my app started crashing on start! Any idea how to fix it?